# Can an airplane on an SVFR clearance land when visibility is less than 1 mile?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, special-vfr

Let's say I'm on an SVFR clearance and the flight and reported ground visibility deteriorates less than 1 mile, what happens?

Answer (score 6):

If the pilot is on an SVFR clearance, the weather inside the surface area deteriorates below 1 mile visibility, and the pilot has the airport in sight, he can inform the controller that he has the field in sight and will be cleared to land. The pilot is responsible for continuing to the airport or exiting the surface area in order to remain visual.

> NOTE− Clear an aircraft to land at an airport with an operating
>   control tower, traffic permitting, if the pilot reports the airport in
>   sight. The pilot is responsible to continue to the airport or exit the
>   surface area. 14 CFR Section 91.157 prohibits VFR aircraft (other than
>   helicopters) from landing at any airport within a surface area when
>   flight visibility is less than 1 mile. A pilot could inadvertently
>   encounter conditions that are below SVFR minimums after entering a
>   surface area due to rapidly changing weather. The pilot is best suited
>   to determine the action to be taken since pilots operating under SVFR
>   between sunrise and sunset are not required to be instrument rated,
>   and the possibility exists that flight visibility may not be the same
>   as ground visibility. 14 CFR Section 91.3 authorizes a pilot
>   encountering an inflight emergency requiring immediate action to
>   deviate from any rule of 14 CFR Part 91 to the extent required to meet
>   that emergency. Flight into adverse weather conditions may require the
>   pilot to execute the emergency authority granted in 14 CFR Section
>   91.3 and continue inbound to land. [Air Traffic Control Handbook, 7−5−4](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/ATC.pdf)

Comment: And if you are instrument rated and current, you can get a popup  instrument clearance.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question? *Confused*

Comment: @Kamran it's allowed and encouraged, it helps SE become a good reference for questions like that.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Got it, I haven't been here long. I need to get to grips with the rules! I can think of a few questions now! I'm glad you cleared this up!

Comment: @casey in these circumstances, you can't get a pop-up. the only place you can get a pop-up in the surface area is on the ground. If you're in the air in the surface area with viz less than 1sm, and you call up the tower and ask them for a pop-up, they will tell you to "maintain VFR" (while they call Approach to coordinate), which you already know you can't do. Even if you can get a clearance, they will ask you if you can provide your own terrain and obstacle clearance while you climb to the MIA or MEA, which you know you also can't do. maybe you can try to fly a DP if you can find the runway:)